# Retrofit multiple POST params

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm trying to submit a call to a server that requires 2 sets of information, this is my interface:

```
@POST("/venues/get-by-location")
void getByLocation(@Body Coordinates coordinates,
                   @Body MaxDistanceBody maxDistance,
                   Callback<MyCallback> callback);
```

but I receive this error: " Multiple @Body method annotations found."

How can I send multiple objects in one Post request? Thanks!

Comment: I think you're probably looking for [multipart requests](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: I did Multipart already and received this: @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #1)

Thats with trying @ PUT and @ POST separately

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/venues/get-by-location")
void getByLocation(@Part("coordinates") Coordinates coordinates,
                   @Part("maxDistanceBody") MaxDistanceBody maxDistance,
                   Callback callback);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to send them as a regular body, you can create a helper class that contains all your values. 
Something like:

### KOTLIN:

```
class VenuesRequestBody(coordinates: Coordinates, maxDistance: MaxDistance)
```

-

```
@POST("/venues/get-by-location")
fun getByLocation(@Body loginRequest: LoginRequest): Call<MyCallback>
```

### JAVA (written without testing):

```
public class VenuesRequestBody {
    Coordinates coordinates;
    MaxDistance maxDistance;

    VenuesRequestBody(Coordinates coordinates, MaxDistance maxDistance) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
        this.maxDistance = maxDistance;
    }
}
```

-

```
@POST("/venues/get-by-location")
void getByLocation(@Body VenuesRequestBody requestBody,
                   Callback<MyCallback> callback);
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this one:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/merchantservice/saveservice")
void SaveServiceApi(
         @Body MultipartTypedOutput file,
         @Body MultipartTypedOutput Videofile,
         @Query("title") String title,
         Callback<ResponseSaveService> callback);
```