# pass two objects in POST retrofit 2.1.0 service

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

How to post multiple objects in POST retrofit service? 
I POST single object and it works fine but now i want to send two objects in POST retrofit web service
Below code for single POST object that works fine

```
   @POST("Device/AddDevice")
   Call<String> addDevice(@Body Device value);
```

I code for multiple objects but it give error

```
    @POST("Device/AddDevice")
    Call<String> addDevice(@Body Device deviceValue , @Body User userValue);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrofit multiple POST params](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25252359/retrofit-multiple-post-params)

Comment: combine them into one using POJO ........

Answer (score 2):

Hi Looks like a duplicate. But here the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25252359/retrofit-multiple-post-params/25252568#25252568)

```
@Multipart
@POST("Device/AddDevice")
void addDevice(@Part("deviceValue") Device coordinates,
                   @Part("userValue") User maxDistance,
                   Callback callback);
```

For more documentation and examples on retrofit have a look at the follwoing page: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client

Comment: This will not work, it return null in the response body. Please answer in retrofit 2.1.0 version.

Comment: Can you give us the complete request with the post content that is sent to the Server. Maybe the Server can't handle the request. So, maybe you need to add a Converter which wraps the body objects in the right format so that the server can process the request.

Comment: @Multipart
    @POST("Device/AddDevice")
    Call<String> addDevice(@Part("DeviceValues") DeviceValues deviceValues, @Part("UserValues") UserValues userValues);

Comment: @Multipart
    @POST("Device/AddDevice")
    Call<String> addDevice(@Part("DeviceValues") DeviceValues deviceValues, @Part("UserValues") UserValues userValues);

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult AddDevice(Device getDevice , User getUser)
        {
            // some work
            return Ok("Result");
        }

Comment: OK, thanks. But I meant what request did the Server actually expect to process a Response. And what did request did you actually sent to the Server? maybe a wireshark snippet or sth similiar

Comment: // Android code
 @Multipart
     @POST("Device/AddDevice")
     Call<String> addDevice(@Part("DeviceValues") DeviceValues deviceValues, @Part("UserValues") UserValues userValues);
 DeviceValues deviceValues = new DeviceValues();
        deviceValues.DeviceInfo = "Jelly Bean";
 UserValues userValues = new UserValues();
        userValues.Email = Data.getUserEmail;
        userValues.Email="some@gmail.com";

Comment: // ASP.NET code
 
 public class DeviceController : ApiController
     {
        EmailToSmsEntities db = new EmailToSmsEntities();
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult AddDevice(Device getDevice , User getUser)
        {
            // some work
            Device device = new Device();
            device.DeviceInfo = getDevice.DeviceInfo;
            User user = new User();
            user.Email=getUser.Email;
            return Ok("Result");
        }
 }

Comment: OK, sorry for the bad english. Seems like we past each other. But what I Need to know is: How would a valid request with post content to the Server would look like? (Something like this:  request: https://url/Device/AddDevice/  and postContent: {"device":"this is a device value", "user":"exmample user" }